# Files corrupted after resizing partitions

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning

So I was trying to move space from my windows partition to Ubuntu partition using Gparted using a live Ubuntu USB disk. Everything was going fine until out of nowhere the screen went black and then 'squashfs' errors started coming up. I forced shut down the system and booted again. Now my files in the windows partition from which I was taking space are corrupted and cannot be opened.
What I did was create an unallocated partition from my C drive in Windows. Now I wanted to merge this with the Ubuntu partition which is placed after the Windows D drive. So I tried to merge this unallocated partition into the D drive and then from the D drive make another unallocated partition and give it to the Ubuntu partition. My windows is working fine, its only my files like documents, photos, etc (which are in the D drive) which wouldn't open although there is no change in their size.
Also the drive size in the explorer and the disk management are inconsistent the former shows the old size for D: while the latter shows the new size for D:

Comment: Do you want to recover the files? or just to make the partitions and filesystem(s) coherent again, even if some data is lost? The `gparted` manual says "You are advised to BACKUP your DATA before using the `gparted` application". Had you followed this advice before you used `gparted`? It will be easier to fully recover if you had.

Comment: Yes I want to recover the files. No I did not backup hence the need to post this question here

Comment: Do you happen to have the gparted logs, or at least the logs from a file system check of D:? What file system is D: anyway, if it's NTFS you should try chkdsk in Windows.